# Find the root key of an hierarchy key value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following lead pairs structure:

```
leads = {
"a":"b",
"b":"d",
"c":"d",
"d":None,
"f":"h",
"h":"j",
"j": None,
"e":None
}
```

I want to extract the root lead associated with every lead.
for example:
lead "a" was acquired by "b" and "c" was acquired by "d" and "d" wasn't acquired by any other lead so he is the root for "a", "b" and "c"

the output that I need is this:

```
[("a","d"),("b","d"),("c","d"),("d",None),("f","j"),("h","j"), ("j",None), ("e", None)]
```

Comment: What have you already tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Not sure how "b" was acquired by "c". Following your logic and looking at the dictionary shouldn't "b" be acquired by "d"?

Comment: fixed the example

Comment: I meant the dictionary was wrong, not the phrasing. Currently the value 'c' is not accessible by any key, "b" will go straight to "d" and skip "c". There is an exhaustive solution for this, however this is probably not what you meant?

Comment: "c" was acquired by "d", "c" is a standalone lead that was acquired by "d". you can see you can see in the requested output that "c","d" is in the tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution:

```
leads = {
"a":"b",
"b":"d",
"c":"d",
"d":None,
"f":"h",
"h":"j",
"j": None,
"e":None
}

r = []
for key, value in leads.items():
    while value in leads and leads[value]:
        value = leads[value]
    r.append((key, value))

print(r)
```

Result:

> [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', None), ('f', 'j'), ('h', 'j'), ('j', None), ('e', None)]